# Excel VBA check 3 cells in row range include a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Range("S4:U72") and I need to make sure that there is only text in either column. Therefore it must not have text in 2 or more columns on the same row.

I know I can use "For each cell in Selection" and I know I can use WorksheetFunction.CountA("S4:U4") > 2

I just don't know how to put the 2 together so that it applies the formula to each row in the table.

Example
[image]

Comment: `=COUNTIF(S4:U72,<string you are looking for>)>2` maybe? It's unclear what you want exactly. Maybe provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out:

```
Dim rng As Range, row As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("S4:U72")

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell In row.Cells
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(row.Cells.Address(0, 0))) > 1 Then
        MsgBox "You can only assign one value to a row"
    End If
  Next cell
Next row
```